# Longest Palindromic Subsequence

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-science

I tried to solve it using recursion. Here's my code. It is failing for "ABDA" (returning 3 instead of 1). The reasoning for this is clear to me but I'm not sure how to fix that.

```
def lps(s):
    print(s)
    n = len(s)
    if n <= 1:
        return n

    if s[0] == s[n-1]:
        return 2 + lps(s[1:-1])
    return max(lps(s[:-1]), lps(s[1:]))
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more intricate examples of expected outputs? I though you were looking for the longest prefix that is also a reverted prefix, but according to MBo's interpretation, you weren't. Are you really speaking about finding the longest palindromic subsequence (eg. "ababa", "cbabc" or "cabac" in "acbabac"), the longest palindromic factor/substring (eg. "bab" in "acbabac"), or was my initial interpretation correct?

Comment: Please specify whether you mean palindromic substring (continuos) or subsequence (`ada` or `aba` in your example)

Comment: 3 is the correct answer according to the [standard meaning of the word *subsequence*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence). If you need something else you better use a different word to name it (substring for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question missed some information to know exactly what you are looking for. I'll assume in the following that you want to find the longest prefix that is also a suffix (in reverse order).

Recursively, the idea is to compare the first and the last characters. If they are not equal, then it cannot be a palindrom (in that case, return 0). If they are equal, the length of that "palindromic part" is 1 + the length of the "palindromic part" of the remaining word (ie. the word without its first and last characters):

```
def lps(word):
  if len(word) > 0 and word[0] == word[-1]:
    return 1 + lps(word[1:-1])
  else:
    return 0

print(lps('abc'))
print(lps('abca'))
print(lps('abba'))
print(lps('abcba'))
print(lps('abda'))
```

results in `0, 1, 2, 3, 1`.

These numbers represent the longest prefix that is (in reverse order) also a suffix.

As you can see, "abba" leads to a length of 2 (because of "ab"), even if its a palindrom of length 4. If you want to get the total length of that palindrom, it's probably easier to do it iteratively:

```
def lps_full(word):
  i = len(word)
  while i > 0:
    if word[:i] == word[:-i-1:-1]:
      return i
    i -= 1
  return 0
```

The same examples lead to `0, 1, 4, 5, 1`, ie., the same results than above for words that are not palindrom, and the length of the word for words that are.

The same function can be defined recursively if it's mandatory for you:

```
def lps(word, i=0):
  if len(word) > i and word[i] == word[-i-1]:
    return lps(word, i+1)
  else:
    return i
```

Comment: print(lps('abac'))

Comment: Seems you mean something else. I'd expect 3 (`aba`)

Comment: Ok, I get it :) I'll update my answer with another function, then ;)

Comment: (Or I won't :-D) Finding the longest palindromic subsequence (or even the longest palindromic factor) is more involved, and the difficulty is probably more related to the algorithm than its implementation.